# Android Provide Different Layout for AppWidget at Lock Screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want 2 separate layouts for homescreen and lockscreen.
I have read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen
But it is unclear where to implement this and how to change the layout at runtime for both homescreen and lockscreen?

I would be grateful if there is clear tutorial / example to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know home screen widget implementation, it's easy. 
From the code below you can figure out how to use different layout for lock screen and home screen to  display the current time every second.

Create different layout for different widgets

@layout/widget_keyguard //For lock screen widget

@layout/widget_home  //For home screen widget

**Note: Use one TextView with id *time_view* on both the layouts to display the time**

xml/widget_info.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_keyguard" // layout for lock screen 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_home"   // layout for lock screen (if not provided) & home screen
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="180000"
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" > //Enable widgets on both home screen and lock screen
</appwidget-provider>
```

AppWidgetProvider.java

```
    public class TestAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @Override
        public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.cancel(sender); //When all the widgets are disabled, do not forget to cancel the service

            super.onDisabled(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context) {

            super.onEnabled(context);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              //AlarmManager to update the widgets
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent p_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                    0);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            // Here I am updating the widgets every second (1000 ms) , you can use however you want
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    1000, p_intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                    TestAppWidgetProvider.class);

            for (int widgetId : appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget)) {

                Bundle myOptions = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(widgetId);
                int category = myOptions.getInt(
                        AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY, -1);

                RemoteViews remoteViews;
                if (category == AppWidgetProviderInfo.WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD) {
                    // Get the remote views
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_keyguard);
                }

                else {
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_home);
                }

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
                 // use TextView with time_view id on both home screen & lock screen layouts
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time_view,
                        dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context,
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId,
                Bundle newOptions) {                
        }

    }
```

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver class

```
    public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(context,
                    TestAppWidgetProvider.class);

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);


            for (int widgetId : appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thiswidget)) {
                Bundle myOptions = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(widgetId);
                int category = myOptions.getInt(
                        AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY, -1);

                RemoteViews remoteViews;
                if (category == AppWidgetProviderInfo.WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD) {
                    // Get the remote views
                    Log.d("Widget", "Lockscreen widget");
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_keyguard);
                }

                else {
                    Log.d("Widget", "Homescreen widget");
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_home);
                }
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

                // use TextView with time_view id on both home screen & lock screen layouts                         
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time_view,
                        dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
            }

        }

    }
```

Finally, do not forget to update the manifest file

```
        <application
            ...

            <receiver android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" />
            <receiver android:name=".TestAppWidgetProvider" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
            </receiver>

        .....
        </application>
```

that's it.

I hope it'll help you to solve your problem

Comment: Thank You @Adarsh Urs. I'm still busy with another project. I cannot try it right now. I think it should work. I will accept your answer. But I think I will not implement it anyway since Android 5.0 has removed ability to put widget on the lock screen.